# Setting a pattern color as backgroundColor of UITableViewRowAction is no longer supported iOS 11

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, ios11

I am getting a log message

> [TableView] Setting a pattern color as backgroundColor of UITableViewRowAction is no longer supported.

Before iOS 11, a pattern color was working fine.

My project uses a custom table view with swipe left to do an action, and in the row action background color I use a 100x100 image.

For example:

```
editAction.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"LeaveRequest_Eng.png"]];
```

I am not able to show that image completely; the image is stretched and does not fill all the area.

Comment: What’s your question?

Comment: Objective c - IOS Iphone Application project developing using xcode. In Xcode console I am getting this message. this is latest IOS update they change pattern color concept. so what is best Practice in this case. my case i am using colorpatternwithimage, that image now not fitting properly, previously it was working fine. @beyowulf

Answer (score 6):

I believe apple is encouraging/forcing you to now use the new `UIContextualAction` api. Previously many developers would use `colorWithPatternImage:` to add images to `UITableViewRowAction` which was always somewhat of a hack and fragile. Beginning with iOS 11 there is now a supported way of adding images to row actions by implementing: `- (UISwipeActionsConfiguration *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`. For example:

```
- (UISwipeActionsConfiguration *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UIContextualAction *editAction = [UIContextualAction contextualActionWithStyle:UIControlStateNormal title:@"Edit" handler:^(UIContextualAction * _Nonnull action, __kindof UIView * _Nonnull sourceView, void (^ _Nonnull completionHandler)(BOOL)) {
        NSLog(@"Do editing");
        completionHandler(YES);
    }];
    editAction.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MyEditImage"];
    editAction.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    return [UISwipeActionsConfiguration configurationWithActions:@[editAction]];
}
```

Comment: But this solution work from IOS 11, what will do if application target lesser-than IOS 11

Comment: Use an `@availible` to target different OS’s

Comment: Can we add a gradient as a background color to `UIContextualAction`?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the swift solution for the same:

```
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

    let message = self.messages[indexPath.row]
    let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Delete") { (action, view, completion) in
         // Perform your action here
        //self.deleteMessage(message: message)
        completion(true)
    }

    let muteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Mute") { (action, view, completion) in
        // Perform your action here
        completion(true)
    }

    deleteAction.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "CheckedMarkRead")
    deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction, muteAction])

}
```